# How to extract number values from a text file and put into an array?

Tags: python

I wanted to code to read a text file and extract the number values out of it and put into an array. I am new to this, does anyone know how to do this? I would appreciate it.
Here's the text file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ayinnc83poulhv7/Booklist.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If the number in new line then you can do it easily like this:

**Update 1:** added rstrip() as per suggestion in comment.

**Update 2:** added file output.

**Python 3 code:**

```
number_list = []
with open("a.txt","r") as fp:
    line_list = fp.readlines()
    for line in line_list:
        line = line.rstrip()
        try:
            number_list.append(int(line))
        except:
            pass
print(number_list)
with open("output.txt","w") as out:
    for i in number_list:
        out.write(str(i)+"\n")
print("File output.txt is generated")
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 14, 20, 24, 26, 31, 32, 33, 35, 40, 46, 50, 52, 54, 56, 66, 100]
File output.txt is generated
```

**output.txt:**

```
2
4
6
10
12
14
20
24
26
31
32
33
35
40
46
50
52
54
56
66
100
```

**a.txt:**

```
The Adventures of Tom Sawyer
2
Huckleberry Finn
4
The Sword in the Stone
6
Stuart Little
10
Treasure Island
12
The Secret Garden
14
Alice's Adventures in Wonderland
20
Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea
24
Peter Pan
26
Charlotte's Web
31
A Little Princess
32
Little Women
33
Black Beauty
35
The Merry Adventures of Robin Hood
40
Robinson Crusoe
46
Anne of Green Gables
50
Little House in the Big Woods
52
Swiss Family Robinson
54
The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe
56
Heidi
66
A Winkle in Time
100
Mary Poppins
```

Comment: why not `line.strip()` instead of `line[:-1]`?

Comment: added rstrip(). Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: I love you guys. Especially arsho. You are a great man and I will remember the fact that you took your time to do this and it has helped me. I noticed some functions I never learned before and it's nice. Thank you!

Comment: Your code reminds my early days of coding. I was facing similar problems but there was no help around. Even I did not know about stackoverflow that time. It is the motive of answering your question as easily as possible. If you found the answer is useful, accept it. :)

Comment: Do you know a way of doing the same thing but with the texts instead? I tried to figure it out but I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Like instead of putting the numbers into an array, you put in the names in the text file instead.

Comment: Umm...that is cool. I guess you misunderstood what I said there, but what I meant was that I wanted to write not the numbers into another "output" text file but the letters instead. Do I use 'int' of some sort?